# Appending query strings to URL

Tags: php, javascript, query-string

> *"Appending an url with appendages that were already in the previous url?"*
>   That's the most confusing title -- I know. But I can't think of a better way to explain it.

Maybe the below example will help.

I have URL 1: `http://example.com/?value=xyz&stuff=abc`

If someone clicks on a link within the page, can I pass along the appended values?

ie: `http://www.example.org/?value=xyz&stuff=abc`

Thanks and sorry for being such a noob.

Comment: How this link is built? With JavaScript or PHP?

Comment: Where's your code. Have you tried anything yet?

Comment: What do you mean pass it along?  Do you want it in the URL?  In PHP, that information is in `$_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']`

Answer (score 7):

These appendages you ask about is the actual so called *query* part of an URI:

```
<scheme>://<authority><path>?<query>

  foo://example.com:8042/over/there?name=ferret#nose
  \_/   \______________/\_________/ \_________/ \__/
   |           |            |            |        |
scheme     authority       path        query   fragment
```

> Taken from: *3. Syntax Components* (RFC 3986) https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986#page-16

You then need a helper function that is append the (optional) `<query>` to an existing `<scheme>://<authority><path>` part. I ignore the `<fragment>` for this exmaple, as it would needed to be added at the end and I want to leave something as an exercise:

```
function href_append_query($href)
{
    $query = isset($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'])
        ? '?' . $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']
        : ''
    ;

    $query = strtr(
        $query, [
            '"' => '&quot;',
            "'" => '&#39;',
            '&' => '&amp;'
        ]
    );

    return $href . $query;
}
```

And it's usage:

```
<a href="<?=href_append_query('http://step2.com/')?>Some link</a>
```

This little function will ensure that the exisitng `QUERY_STRING` which can be obtained via [`$_SERVER`<sup>*Docs*</sup>](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php) is encoded for HTML output.

Answer (score 3):

If links are built with PHP, just append the original query string to them:

```
<a href="http://step2.com/?<?php echo $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']; ?>">Some link</a>
```

In JavaScript, just append the value of `window.location.search` to all the links you need to 'pass' the query string.

Answer (score 0):

You could also use js/jquery to append the existing query string to each link on the page:

```
 $(function() {
    $('a').each(function() {
      link = $(this).attr('href');
      query = window.location.search;
      if (link.indexOf('?') !== -1 && query !== '') {
        query = query.replace('?','&');
      }
      $(this).attr('href',link+query);
    });
  });
```